# Enable/disable text box on check/uncheck box

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox that is enabled by default.

The issue here is that once i uncheck it, it remains disabled even when i check it back again.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="show-check" checked value="1" id="DisplayOnClick">

document.getElementById("DisplayOnClick").onclick = function(){
        if(document.getElementById("DisplayOnClick").checked){
            document.getElementById("myFieldset").style.display = "block";

        } else {       
            document.getElementById("myFieldset").disabled = !this.checked;          
        }
    }
```

Also tried this following code but this doesn't do anything.

```
$(function () {

        $("#DisplayOnClick").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is("checked")){
                $("#myFieldset").show();
            }else {
                $("#myFieldset").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why do you have 2 listeners for clicking the checkbox?

Comment: @BryanDellinger leaving that aside (which is incorrect almost for sure, it should be one, of course) ... I tried both codes independently and they worked.

Comment: @lealceldeiro it doesn't work on my machine for some reason. It stays disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {

$("#DisplayOnClick").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#myFieldset").removeAttr('disabled')
        }else {
            $("#myFieldset").attr('disabled', 'true')   
        }
    });
});
```

This should do what you want.

The selector for the checkbox needs to be `:checked`

Also a thing I ran into with fieldsets it would seem, is that even if you set `disabled=false`, it's still disabled. It doesn't care what the value of disabled is, only that it exists.

Comment: really? that should definitely work. Are you sure you have JQuery available?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do anything at all.  The top part of my code disables the input but doesn't enable it back on.

Comment: It would help me if I knew what `#myFieldset` was

Comment: It's a form. I have this code for it. <%if(currentUser.isPresentValue()){%>
<fieldset id="myFieldset" >
    <%}else {%>
        <fieldset disabled="disabled" id="myFieldset" >
    <%}%>

Comment: See the changes I made to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just doing the following worked for me.

```
document.getElementById("DisplayOnClick").onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("myFieldset").disabled = !this.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at is checked if it is checked then show the fieldset else hide.

```js
$('#DisplayOnClick').click((e) => $('#myfieldset')[$(e.target).is(':checked') ? 'show' : 'hide']());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="show-check" checked value="1" id="DisplayOnClick">
<div id="myfieldset">
  hello from my field set
</div>
```